# TFS Query charts on TFS 2013 Web acces

Tags: charts, tfs-web-access

stackoverflow community,

In TFS 2013 web access, Is there way a to show the Story Point trend based on all the Tasks linked to a User Story closing? That is, If all Tasks linked to a User Story are closed, the trend line should drop by the corresponding Story Point value of the User Story irrespective of its State.

I tried to do a Query Chart using work items and direct links instead of the Flat list, but it would not let me. Looks like the ability to do a Query Chart is restricted to Flat list.

The filter is by an iteration..

Any other solutions available?

Answer (score 0):

No, this can't be achieved by TFS query chars on TFS2013 Web access. And there has been a related feature request, you can also vote up it.

> [Add Story Point burndown to dashboard and reports](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/4473980-add-story-point-burndown-to-dashboard-and-reports#%7Btoggle_previous_statuses%7D)
>
> The work is still in progress and we’re tracking it closely on our
>   roadmap. The goal is to have something available in the first half of
>   next year. I’ll update this topic as soon as we have more info.
>
> *Team Services Group (Product group, Microsoft Visual Studio) responded  June 03, 2016*